# Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct' error when applying tags in typescript cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a parameter and then use the value of that parameter in a tag inside cdk (typesript). But when I am creating using the below code I am getting the error on "this"

```
const EnvironmentType = new CfnParameter(this, "EnvironmentType", {
  type: "String",
  allowedValues: ["prod", "qa", "sandbox"],
  description: "The name of the Amazon S3 bucket where uploaded files will be stored."});
```

The error is

> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Construct'.ts

Below is the complete code if anyone wants to have a look.

```
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { CfnParameter, Tags, Duration, RemovalPolicy, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Stream } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-kinesis';
import { Queue } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

interface StatefulStackProps extends StackProps {
  readonly config: {
    readonly streamId: string;
    readonly streamName: string;
    readonly streamExportName: string;
  };
  readonly envName: string;
}

const EnvironmentType = new CfnParameter(this, "EnvironmentType", {
  type: "String",
  allowedValues: ["prod", "qa", "sandbox"],
  description: "The name of the Amazon S3 bucket where uploaded files will be stored."});


export class TrackerStatefulResourcesStack extends Stack {
  readonly clickIngestStream: Stream;
  readonly clickIngestDLQ: Queue;
  readonly clickTotalsQueue: Queue;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StatefulStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.clickIngestStream = new Stream(this, props.config.streamId, {
      streamName: props.config.streamName,
      retentionPeriod: Duration.days(7),
      shardCount: 1,
    });

    this.exportValue(this.clickIngestStream.streamName, {
      name: props.config.streamExportName,
    });

    this.clickIngestDLQ = new Queue(this, 'ClickIngestDLQ', {
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
      retentionPeriod: Duration.days(14),
    });

    const clickTotalsDLQ = new Queue(this, 'ClickTotalsDLQ', {
      fifo: true,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
      retentionPeriod: Duration.days(14),
    });

    this.clickTotalsQueue = new Queue(this, 'ClickTotalsQueue', {
      fifo: true,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
      retentionPeriod: Duration.days(14),
      contentBasedDeduplication: true,
      deliveryDelay: Duration.seconds(65),
      deadLetterQueue: {
        queue: clickTotalsDLQ,
        maxReceiveCount: 3,
      },
    });
    Tags.of(this).add('EnvironmentType', EnvironmentType.valueAsString);
    Tags.of(this).add('product', 'abc');
    Tags.of(this).add('product-owner', 'abc');
    Tags.of(this).add('team', 'data team');
    Tags.of(this).add('technical-help', 'abc');
  }
}
```

Comment: You can only create constructs inside of a stack. Move the code into the stack for it to work.

Comment: The [AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnParameter.html) says: "... it is recommended that parameters are defined at the stack level." But apart of that, i wonder: Didn't you get a syntax error on `new CfnParameter(this, ...` ? `this` shouldn't be resolved in this context - especially not as a `Construct`.